# JQuery/MVC4 - Is there a way to preventing "DataTables" plug-in to overwrite my clases

Tags: jquery, css, class, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Using ASP .NET MVC 4 and DataTables jQuery plug-in (found here: http://datatables.net/ )

My problem is that in my initial table HTML code, I have some custom classes on 'tr' tags that are generated on server side depending on some model properties.
Since I've installed this jQuery plug-in, ok my tables now have sort, filter, pages etc.
But the plug-in overwrites my 'tr' class attributes.

I thought that the plug-in could have used something like addClass/removeClass instead of rewriting all classes.

Does anybody know a solution ? Thank you.

PS: I forgot to mention: I have included the minified version of "DataTables" and I would like a solution that doesn't require me to edit this library.

Comment: By "overwrite", do you mean the classes are being removed and replaced?

Comment: look at the source and see what classes are being put on the tr's, then call those in your css

Comment: Blazemonger: Yes, that's what I mean.